# BottomNavigation, FragmentManager has not been attached to a host

Tags: java, android, android-studio, kotlin, bottomnavigationview

I have moved BottomNavigation codes from MainActivity to A class I have created for the BottomNaviction to make the code more organizing. When I moved the codes I got this error `java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.moataz.mox/com.moataz.mox.ui.view.activity.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: FragmentManager has not been attached to a host.` Short error message `FragmentManager has not been attached to a host`.

**And The error In this line of code**

```
// The error is here
final FragmentManager fragmentManager = fragmentActivity.getSupportFragmentManager();
```

**Here's My BottomNavigation Class**

```
public class BottomNavigation extends BottomNavigationView {

FragmentActivity fragmentActivity = new FragmentActivity();

final Fragment homeFragment = new HomeFragment();
final Fragment searchFragment = new SearchFragment();
final Fragment videosFragment = new VideosFragment();
final Fragment favouriteFragment = new FavouriteFragment();
final Fragment premiumFragment = new PremiumFragment();
// The error is here
final FragmentManager fragmentManager = fragmentActivity.getSupportFragmentManager();
Fragment mainFragment = homeFragment;

public BottomNavigation(@NonNull Context context) {
    super(context);
}

@SuppressLint("NonConstantResourceId")
public void initializeBottomNavigation() {
    // first one transaction to add each Fragment
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
    fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.fragment_layout, premiumFragment, "5").hide(premiumFragment);
    fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.fragment_layout, favouriteFragment, "4").hide(favouriteFragment);
    fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.fragment_layout, videosFragment, "3").hide(videosFragment);
    fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.fragment_layout, searchFragment, "2").hide(searchFragment);
    fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.fragment_layout, homeFragment, "1");
    // commit once! to finish the transaction
    fragmentTransaction.commit();

    // show and hide them when click on BottomNav items
    BottomNavigationView navigationView = findViewById(R.id.bottom_navigation);
    navigationView.setOnItemSelectedListener(item -> {
        // start a new transaction
        FragmentTransaction localFragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        // TODO: ADD Animations
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.home_item:
                localFragmentTransaction.hide(mainFragment).show(homeFragment).commit();
                mainFragment = homeFragment;
                return true;

            case R.id.search_item:
                localFragmentTransaction.hide(mainFragment).show(searchFragment).commit();
                mainFragment = searchFragment;
                return true;

            case R.id.videos_item:
                localFragmentTransaction.hide(mainFragment).show(videosFragment).commit();
                mainFragment = videosFragment;
                return true;

            case R.id.saved_item:
                localFragmentTransaction.hide(mainFragment).show(favouriteFragment).commit();
                mainFragment = favouriteFragment;
                return true;

            case R.id.premium_item:
                localFragmentTransaction.hide(mainFragment).show(premiumFragment).commit();
                mainFragment = premiumFragment;
                return true;
        }
        return false;
    });
}
```

And here I haved Called my class and method In MainActivity

```
private void initializeBottomNavigation() {
BottomNavigation bottomNavigation = new BottomNavigation(this);
bottomNavigation.initializeBottomNavigation();

}
```

---

**I have tried to find a sloution and anderstand the error but I didn't found sothing In my case. So what is the problem here and How can I fix It?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot make a new instance of an activity; activity instances are built only by Android itself. The only thing you can do in order to obtain an activity reference is to use an existing one.

```
public class BottomNavigation extends BottomNavigationView {

    final FragmentActivity fragmentActivity;
    ...
    final FragmentManager fragmentManager;
    
    public BottomNavigation(@NonNull Context context, @NonNull FragmentActivity activity) {
        super(context);
        fragmentActivity = activity;
        fragmentManager = fragmentActivity.getSupportFragmentManager();
    }

    ...
}
```

And pass your existing reference of your activity:

```
private void initializeBottomNavigation() {
    FragmentActivity activity = this; // Or your activity reference
    BottomNavigation bottomNavigation = new BottomNavigation(this, activity);
    bottomNavigation.initializeBottomNavigation();
}
```

Note that you still need to attach your `BottomNavigation` to a view parent in the activity to make it visible.

Comment: This is a great explanation, thank you for that. Have a great day.